# Moment.js always returns 'a few seconds ago'

Tags: javascript, momentjs

From the docs:

"To get the current date and time, just call `moment()` with no parameters.

```
var now = moment();
```

This is essentially the same as calling `moment(new Date())`.

Note: From version 2.14.0, `moment([])` and `moment({})` also return now. They used to default to start-of-today before 2.14.0, but that was arbitrary so it was changed."

I have tried both

```
moment().fromNow()
```

and also

```
moment(new Date()).fromNow()
```

and a lot of other options. Upon page refresh, the time always displays 'a few seconds ago'.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry for the lousy formatting

Comment: can you show some code where you use these commands, how you consume the data, and how you are showing it on the page?

Comment: This is how I'm calling it in my code:
<div className='runDate'>{moment(new Date()).fromNow()}</div>

Comment: please [edit] the question;  don't put code in comments.

Comment: also, what are you *expecting* as an output?  you are asking it to get the current date and time, and calculate how long the current date and time is from the current date and time, they will always only be a second (the time for both calls to be made) apart.

Comment: I'm hoping that if I post an item, I can view it the next day and see 'posted 1 day ago' next to the item, instead of 'just a moment ago'

Comment: well in that case, you need to get the `new Date()` when the post is created, and it needs to be saved to a field in the database within the item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fromNow` method, compares a date you pass to `moment()` to the date and time it is now, when you call that method.

It will always return `a few seconds ago` if you pass nothing or `new Date()` to `moment()` because it will be comparing it to moment's version of now (probably calling `new Date()` at some point). The difference between these two dates will always be equal or a few milliseconds difference.

If you are looking to display the time difference from a date, you need to pass the comparison date into `moment` like so:

```
var date = '2016-04-09 02:57:00';

var diff = moment(date).fromNow(); // 'A year ago'
```

Sample outputs and similar comparison methods can be found on the moment docs http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Answer (score 6):

In order to get exactly how many seconds ago, you can do something like this.

```
function timeAgo(time) {
    moment.updateLocale('en', {
        relativeTime: {
            future: "in %s",
            past: "%s ago",
            s: number=>number + "s ago",
            ss: '%ds ago',
            m: "1m ago",
            mm: "%dm ago",
            h: "1h ago",
            hh: "%dh ago",
            d: "1d ago",
            dd: "%dd ago",
            M: "a month ago",
            MM: "%d months ago",
            y: "a year ago",
            yy: "%d years ago"
        }
    });

    let secondsElapsed = moment().diff(time, 'seconds');
    let dayStart = moment("2018-01-01").startOf('day').seconds(secondsElapsed);

    if (secondsElapsed > 300) {
        return moment(time).fromNow(true);
    } else if (secondsElapsed < 60) {
        return dayStart.format('s') + 's ago';
    } else {
        return dayStart.format('m:ss') + 'm ago';
    }
},
```

The result will be

> 2s ago

Answer (score 0):

You are using `moment(new Date())` which is going to return `now` and then calling `fromNow()`. So the time difference is always going to be 0 seconds (or a few milliseconds) so thats what is getting displayed.

You should pass in some date to moment like:

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

And then call `fromNow()` on it so as to get time difference between that date and `now`.

Answer (score 0):

Moment's duration's humanize function allows you to pass thresholds
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize

By default you will get:

```
moment.duration(35 * 1000).humanize() // a few seconds
```

If you pass threshold for ss

```
moment.duration(35 * 1000).humanize({ss: 1}) // 35 seconds
```